# Remover pontuação e símbolos em Python

Tags: string, python-2.7

Estou tentando remover os símbolos de pontuação e outros símbolos (caracteres como copyright, por exemplo) de uma string.

Quero deixar os os caracteres acentuados, o hífen, o apóstrofo ('), o espaço em branco, além das letras e números.

Como fazer isso em python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta utilizar regex:

```
import re

string_nova = re.sub(u'[^a-zA-Z0-9áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ: ]', '', string_velha.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Sua sugestão removeu a pontuação, mas também removeu os caracteres acentuados. Eu gostaria de mantê-los.

Comment: Opa! Desculpa o engano, editei o código. Agora deve resolver o seu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode selecionar os caracteres um por um para removê-los.

```
def chr_remove(old, to_remove):
    new_string = old
    for x in to_remove:
        new_string = new_string.replace(x, '')
    return new_string
```

assim você pode remover apenas os caracteres desejados. Ex:

```
> s = "string $com (caracteres#."
> print chr_remove(s, "$(#") # remove $,# e ( da string
string com caracteres.
```

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, mas dessa forma fica um pouco inviável prever todos os símbolos que podem aparecer