# Substituição de lista com padrão em regex

Tags: python-3.x, string, regex, lista

Pessoal preciso transformar uma string em lista, de uma forma peculiar.

Encontrei [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209288/python-split-string-based-on-regex) o que preciso fazer. Mas estou perdido quanto ao regex aplicado.

Tenho inúmeras string no seguinte formato:

```
["DECRETO Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",   
'DECRETO Nº  76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
'DECRETO-LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
'LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
"Decreto Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975",
"Decreto Nº 76.326 de 23 DE Setembro de 1975.",
"DECRETO - LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",
"DECRETO- LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",
"DECRETO -LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975."]
```

Meu objetivo final é transformá-las para que elas fiquem assim:

```
"DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975" ou

"DECRETO Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975" ou

"LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975"
```

Pensei em transformá-las em lista com regex e `join` para voltar a string, mas creio que possa haver uma forma mais simples.

```
def truncus22():
    ''''''
    s = 'DECRETO-LEI nº  76.326 De 23 de setembro de 1975.'
    s = re.sub('\.$', '', re.sub('  ', ' ', s))
    return ', '.join(re.split("(?<!^)\s+(?=D)(?!.\s)", s)).upper()
```

Olha aqui pessoal um exemplo que eu havia pensado. Mas funciona apenas em 01 dos casos apresentados...

Preciso editar a string original, removendo os espaços duplicados, acrescentar vírgula antes da data, remover espaços no hífem, e o ponto final, de todas as strings

Comment: O que exatamente muda da primeira lista para a segunda? Os espaços e a vírgula?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim. preciso editar a string original, removendo os espaços duplicados, acrescentar vírgula antes da data, remover espaços no hífem, e o ponto final, de todas as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> editar a string original, removendo os espaços duplicados,
> acrescentar vírgula antes da data, remover espaços no hífem, e o ponto
> final, de todas as strings.

Para solucionar **com Expressões Regulares**, a remoção de caracteres (espaço em branco e ponto) é separado da inserção de caracteres (vírgula).

## Regex

#### Remover caracteres

A seguinte expressão regular é utilizada para verificar espaçamentos múltiplos, espaçamento no hífem e ponto final:

`\s+(?=\s|-)|(?<=-)\s+|\.$`

E a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/3) pode ser vista no link.

#### Adicionar Caracteres

A seguinte expressão regular é utilizada para verificar a data e inserir a vírgula:

`(?<!,)\s(?=de\s\d{1,2}\sde\s[a-zç]+\sde\s\d{4})` com a flag IGNORECASE

E a [demo no Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/5) pode ser vista aqui.

## Código

```
# coding=utf-8
import re


frases =   ["DECRETO Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",
            'DECRETO Nº  76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
            'DECRETO-LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
            'LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.',
            "Decreto Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975",
            "Decreto Nº 76.326 de 23 DE Setembro de 1975.",
            "DECRETO - LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",
            "DECRETO- LEI Nº     76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975.",
            "DECRETO -LEI Nº  76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975."]

print """
VERIFICAÇÃO DE ESPAÇOS EXTRAS (2 ou mais) ou espaçamento do hífem OU PONTO FINAL
https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/3
"""

padrao_regex = re.compile(r"\s+(?=\s|-)|(?<=-)\s+|\.$")
substituicoes = [re.sub(padrao_regex, "", frase) for frase in frases]
if substituicoes:
    for substituicao in substituicoes:
        print substituicao

print """
VERIFICAÇÃO DE DATAS
https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/5
"""

padrao_regex = re.compile(r"(?<!,)\s(?=\d{1,2}\sde\s[a-zç]+\sde\s\d{4})", re.IGNORECASE)
resultados = [re.sub(padrao_regex, ", ", substituicao) for substituicao in substituicoes]
if resultados:
    for resultado in resultados:
        print resultado
```

Em que as substituições por Regex são realizadas com um loop nas listas da seguinte maneira: `[re.sub(padrao_regex, "caractere de substituição", item) for item in lista]`

## Resultado

```
VERIFICAÇÃO DE ESPAÇOS EXTRAS (2 ou mais) ou espaçamento do hífem OU PONTO FINAL
https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/3

DECRETO Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
Decreto Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
Decreto Nº 76.326 de 23 DE Setembro de 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326 DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975

VERIFICAÇÃO DE DATAS
https://regex101.com/r/SVEi1X/5

DECRETO Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
Decreto Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
Decreto Nº 76.326, de 23 DE Setembro de 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
DECRETO-LEI Nº 76.326, DE 23 DE SETEMBRO DE 1975
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> lei = ["lei n32 .....", "lei n43 ....."]
>>> lei[1]
'lei n43 .....'
>>> lei[0]
'lei n32 .....'
>>> lei1 = lei[0]
>>> lei1
'lei n32 .....'
>>> lei2 = lei[1]
>>> lei2
'lei n43 .....'
>>>
```

Com o exemplo acima ele trata a variável lei como `array`, sendo assim, só é necessário pedir `lei[indice]` e ele vai retornar o valor na posição `indice` ou ainda passar o valor de `lei[indice]` para uma variável comum.

Comment: Valeu mais, O objetivo não é pegar os elementos do array, e sim Formatá-los para que fiquem como no objetivo final.

Comment: Veja se este link lhe ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124088/remover-pontua%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-s%C3%ADmbolos-em-python

Comment: Para tirar o ponto no final, tudo bem. Mas quanto a colocar a virgula depois da numeração e antes da data, nas strings?

Comment: @britodfbr Sua pergunta não está clara, edite ela novamente. Favor, crie um [mcve] para a pergunta. Pois a pergunta está muito ampla e quando [você é mais específico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1481/75104), há mais chances de sua pergunta ser respondida corretamente.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, o que posso melhorar na pergunta? Mostrei o que tenho, que no caso colequei as diferentes strings em uma lista. E na sequencia o objetivo esperado. 

Também colequei a linha que estou seguindo para tentar resolver...

Comment: @britodfbr Achei confusa, pois você falou "preciso transformar uma string em lista", mas no fim parece que você possui listas e quer transformar em string e depois voltar para lista? fiquei confuso. E ao que me parece não é necessário regex.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, tenho strings no formato que apresento na primeira lista, são as possibilidades possíveis que há, como ligeiras diferenças entre elas.

E preciso formatá-las colocando vírgula antes da data e retirar o ponto final após o ano.

Comment: Eu entendi o seu objetivo, bom, te dei este exemplo de mostrar as frases e o link com o uso o chr_remove() segue este outro link http://blog.evaldojunior.com.br/aulas/python/2008/11/30/curso-de-python-aula-6-um-pouco-mais-sobre-strings.html  acho que se você juntar tudo isso... você chega no seu resultado.\

Comment: Praticamente tratar a string como char de várias posições